# Postsharp .net intercept try catch

Tags: .net, aop, postsharp

I am working on an existing .net application and we want to add more logging information without modifying on the existing codes sources by using the PostSharp library.

Is it possible that we intercept the try catch event ?
the idea is that we put logging each time we had a catched exception..

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have tried to add this code: [assembly: LogAspectAttribute(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes="System.Exception")] or [assembly: LogAspectAttribute(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "System", AttributeTargetTypes="System.Exception")]  but it's not working..

Comment: can you show some of your code that throws/should handle the exception?

Comment: Normally, PostSharp's OnMethodBoundary aspect can handle this interception points for a method: entry, success, exception, exit (invoked for both success and exception cases). If you catch the exception inside your method and don't rethrow it, then OnMethodBoundary aspect doesn't have chance to know about it. Some example of what you're trying to achieve would certainly help.